# Checking if a value is equal to any value in an array

Tags: python

I'm new to python (and programming in general) and I can't seem to find a solution to this by myself. I want to check the first letter of a string is equal to any letter stored in an array, something like this:

```
letter = ["a", "b", "c"]
word = raw_input('Enter a word:')
first = word[0]

if first == letter:
    print "Yep"
else:
    print "Nope"
```

But this doesn't work, does anyone know how it will? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have no idea how long I spent on trying to fix this stupid issue and how relieved I was when I found an exact answer on the exact same problem hahahah.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `in` operator. Use `if first in letter:`.

```
>>> letter = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> word = raw_input('Enter a word:')
Enter a word:ant
>>> first = word[0]
>>> first in letter
True
```

And one False test,

```
>>> word = raw_input('Enter a word:')
Enter a word:python
>>> first = word[0]
>>> first in letter
False
```

Answer (score 11):

The hint is in your question. Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).  This uses a generator expression to check if it is True or False.

```
any(first == c for c in letter)
```

Comment: This question might be marked as duplicate, but it's the first result I found in Google when seeking a quick refresher. IMO, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `in` keyword:

```
if first in letter:
```

On your current code, you are comparing a string character (`first` which equals the first character in `word`) to a list.  So, let's say my input is `"a word"`.  What your code is actually doing is:

```
if "a" == ["a", "b", "c"]:
```

which will always be false.

Using the `in` keyword however is doing:

```
if "a" in ["a", "b", "c"]:
```

which tests whether `"a"` is a member of `["a", "b", "c"]` and returns true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it, is that you are asking does a character equal an array. This will always return false.

Try using a loop to check 'first' against each item in 'letter'. Let me know if you need help on figuring out how to do this.